# Why isn't it possible use names of variables in Java?

Tags: java, pointers

For example, let's say I wanted to create 5 variables like so:

```
int a1 = 1;
int a2 = 2;
int a3 = 3;
int a4 = 4;
int a5 = 5;
```

Why is it not possible to do it using a loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    int "a"+i = i; // syntax is just an example
```

Or even:

```
int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    "a"+i = i; // syntax is just an example
```

I'm assuming this isn't possible considering I've never seen it done. But why not? Is it just syntactically impossible? Or is it because its implementation would introduce many more issues than advantages?

In some situations it would be nice to be able to algorithmically refer to pointers based upon their very names.

Comment: Because the inventors of Java decided to not support that feature.  Very few other languages support it either.

Comment: Aside from anything else, it encourages writing that sort of code - rather than the more elegant approproach of `int[] a = new int[5]`...

Comment: Check [this](http://arshajii.com/coding-faqs/dynamic-vars.html) out.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java is Strongly typed language.
According to  [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html)

> The Java programming language is a strongly typed language, which means that every variable and every expression has a type that is known at compile time. Strong typing helps detect errors at compile time.

Comment: Java also has reflection, which is strongly typed only in letter. Therefore this argument doesn't preclude reflecting on local variables: you could make a reflective reference to a local var have the type `LocalVar` and leave the rest to the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do cannot be done using dynamic variable naming in Java, that just wouldn't be syntactically valid. There are better ways to do this, like using an array:

```
int[] a = new int[5];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
a[4] = 5;

for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++) {
   a[i] = i;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it because its implementation would introduce many more issues than advantages?

Yes, you are basically right with that statement. Local variables are in good part about top efficiency and any mechanism which allowed them to be reflectively referred to at runtime would not be able to match the performance of the actual system, where the local variable name is used to just "conect the dots" at the machine-code level and the variable is most probably a CPU register or a hardcoded stack offset.

Being able to refer to local variables would cause conceptual issues as well: it would make local vars first-class, therefore such a reference could be returned from a method. Clearly, returning a local var from a method is an ill-defined concept.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve is a little more tricky...

```
Map<String, Integer> arrayLikeMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    arrayLikeMap.put("a"+i, i);
}
```

And you can get the value as `arrayLikeMap.get("a"+1);`

Comment: Though using array makes it more easier.